# Is there a way to copy files with a batch file to the folder that batch file is in?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, drive-letter

So I am trying to make a batch file to sync an external hard drive.
My hard drive is not always connected to the same letter, so i cannot just make a batch file with `xcopy F:\Folder1 G:\backupharddrive` because `G:\backupharddrive`would be variable

Is there a way to just copy to the folder the batch file is in?

Comment: Did you tried `xcopy F:\Folder1 .`?

Comment: That works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Another good thing to know about batch is that you can get the current directory and path of the batch file by using the %0 variable and its modifiers. `%~dp0` would give the path the batch file is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use relative addressing, where `.` represents the current directory.

```
xcopy F:\Folder1 .
```

For future reference, you can also access the parent of the current folder (IOW, 1 level higher up in the directory tree) using `..`. This makes it handy to move up a level, or even over one. For instance, to copy files from `C:\Temp\One` to `C:\Temp\Two`, you can use

```
xcopy *.* ..\Two\
```

which means *copy the files from this folder up one level and then over to the Two folder*.

If you use `dir` from a command prompt, you'll see that in any level below the drive root you'll have items for `.` and `..` in the list. (The root only has `.`, because it has no parent folder.